# When I remove the <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> from the manifest the the application starts from the 2nd activity

Tags: java, android

When I add

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

in the manifest file, the application starts from the 2nd activity.
If I don't put the action,

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

then the application does not start.
If I remove

```
<intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

The Gradle gives an error.
"Error running Main2Activity: The activity must be exported or contain an intent-filter"

here is my code for manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.dell_7560.experiment3">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Main2Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main2">

            <!--if I remove this, I get an error mentioned above-->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity 1 file

```
package com.example.dell_7560.experiment3;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    LinearLayout ll;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll1);
        ll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

activity 2 file

```
package com.example.dell_7560.experiment3;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        poupulateListView();
    }
    public void poupulateListView() {
        //get the values from res
        Resources res=getResources();
        String data_items[]=res.getStringArray(R.array.details);

        //build a adapter
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,//using a default layout
                        data_items)//elements fed to the adapter
         {
             @Override
             public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
             {
                View view=super.getView(position,convertView,parent);
                TextView tv=(TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.occurYellow));
                return view;
             }
         };
        //why do we android before R? cause normally we use R.id.something

        //configure the adapter
        ListView lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view_1);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

manifest file only add between application tag below line.

```
  <activity android:name=".Main2Activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"/>
```

In manifest file only first activity which call on app start that activity add only intent filter other then activity only called above code.

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

In the manifests tells the launcher which is the main activity to launch. Those 2 things must be present so it is recognised as an activity to be launch.

If you have 2 activities with this intent filter, and from the first one you remove one of the parameters, its not recognised anymore and the next one matching will be used. In this case, your second activity.

Comment: If I remove the intent filter from the second activity I get Error running Main2Activity: The activity must be exported or contain an intent-filter

Comment: One activity only must contain this intent filter, not multiple ones.

Comment: Yes, I agree. After removing the intent filter I get Error running Main2Activity: The activity must be exported or contain an intent-filter, how do I solve this?

Comment: If you remove the intent filter you cannot run in Android Studio directly the activity 2. You should reselect in the dropwdown the Main Activity, otherwise you cannot run it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

This is to indicate that this activity is the activity that android must be start when open the app. You should have one activity with this.